# I created a pin box, even when I type the right pin it says wrong

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a Pin Box project, In which the user has to input the pin, and then I have to check it to tell the user if it is right or not. When I type the wrong answer it says *wrong* which is expected but when I type the right pin it again says *wrong* which is not expected.
So please help me to find the mistake and give me some suggestions.

**HTML**

```js
let pinInput = form.box.value;
let pass = "1234";
let pass2 = 1234;
let attempts = 5;
function submit_func() {
  if (attempts >= 1) {
    if (pinInput == pass || pinInput == pass2) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Right";
    } else {
      attempts -= 1;
      document.getElementById(
        "result"
      ).innerHTML = `Wrong, Attempts left ${attempts}`;
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You are out of attempts";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
main {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#box {
  display: block;
  grid-column: 1/4;
  background-color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
  color: #fff;
}
form {
  height: 60%;
  width: 25%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  box-shadow: 1rem 1rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.btn {
  background-color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
  color: #fff;
}
.btn:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}
.reset {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 5/6;
}
.ok_btn {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 5/6;
}
#result {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Pin Box</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <form name="form" id="form">
        <input type="text" name="box" id="box" autocomplete="off" />

        <input
          type="button"
          class="btn"
          value="1"
          onclick="form.box.value += '1'"
        />
        <input
          type="button"
          class="btn"
          value="2"
          onclick="form.box.value += '2'"
        />
        <input
          type="button"
          class="btn"
          value="3"
          onclick="form.box.value += '3'"
        />
        <input
          type="button"
          class="btn"
          value="4"
          onclick="form.box.value += '4'"
        />
        <input
          type="button"
          class="btn"
          value="5"
          onclick="form.box.value += '5'"
        />
        <input
          type="button"
          class="btn"
          value="6"
          onclick="form.box.value += '6'"
        />
        <input
          type="button"
          class="btn"
          value="7"
          onclick="form.box.value += '7'"
        />
        <input
          type="button"
          class="btn"
          value="8"
          onclick="form.box.value += '8'"
        />
        <input
          type="button"
          class="btn"
          value="9"
          onclick="form.box.value += '9'"
        />
        <input
          type="button"
          class="btn"
          value="0"
          onclick="form.box.value += '0'"
        />
        <input
          type="button"
          class="btn ok_btn"
          value="OK"
          onclick="submit_func()"
        />
        <button type="reset" class="btn reset">Clear</button>
      </form>
      <p id="result"></p>
    </main>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*I am learning JS*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are not updating pinInput to its current value when you are testing it so it always has the original (null) value.

So, alter your JS to:

```
let pinInput = form.box.value;
let pass = "1234";
let pass2 = 1234;
let attempts = 5;
function submit_func() {
  
  pinInput = form.box.value;
  if (attempts >= 1) {
    if (pinInput == pass || pinInput == pass2) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Right";
    } else {
      attempts -= 1;
      document.getElementById(
        "result"
      ).innerHTML = `Wrong, Attempts left ${attempts}`;
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You are out of attempts";
  }
}
```

Having said that, here is a note of caution. This is not a secure way of checking a pin. The user can easily go into their dev tools and see how their input is being checked and put in the right answer.

To have security you will need to do the checking out of reach of the user on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

`pinInput` will *always* be an empty string because you're setting the variable value before your submit function is called. Have `let pinInput = form.box.value;` be the first line in the function instead so it actually picks up the value in the box after you've added some numbers.

```js
let pass = "1234";
let pass2 = 1234;
let attempts = 5;

function submit_func() {
  let pinInput = form.box.value;
  if (attempts >= 1) {
    if (pinInput == pass || pinInput == pass2) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Right";
    } else {
      attempts -= 1;
      document.getElementById(
        "result"
      ).innerHTML = `Wrong, Attempts left ${attempts}`;
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You are out of attempts";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#box {
  display: block;
  grid-column: 1/4;
  background-color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
  color: #fff;
}

form {
  height: 60%;
  width: 25%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  box-shadow: 1rem 1rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.btn {
  background-color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
  color: #fff;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.reset {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 5/6;
}

.ok_btn {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 5/6;
}

#result {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <form name="form" id="form">
    <input type="text" name="box" id="box" autocomplete="off" />
    <input type="button" class="btn" value="1" onclick="form.box.value += '1'" />
    <input type="button" class="btn" value="2" onclick="form.box.value += '2'" />
    <input type="button" class="btn" value="3" onclick="form.box.value += '3'" />
    <input type="button" class="btn" value="4" onclick="form.box.value += '4'" />
    <input type="button" class="btn" value="5" onclick="form.box.value += '5'" />
    <input type="button" class="btn" value="6" onclick="form.box.value += '6'" />
    <input type="button" class="btn" value="7" onclick="form.box.value += '7'" />
    <input type="button" class="btn" value="8" onclick="form.box.value += '8'" />
    <input type="button" class="btn" value="9" onclick="form.box.value += '9'" />
    <input type="button" class="btn" value="0" onclick="form.box.value += '0'" />
    <input type="button" class="btn ok_btn" value="OK" onclick="submit_func()" />
    <button type="reset" class="btn reset">Clear</button>
  </form>
  <p id="result"></p>
</main>
```